# Automated RDS snapshots doesn't match with configuration

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have automated backup on my AWS RDS MySQL service configured for 3 days, but when I look at the automated snapshots there are 5 backups corresponding to the last 5 days. I think I reduced from 5 to 3 days, but that was a long time ago. Even if I delete the backups and return a week later, still there are 5 backups. Anybody know what is going on? Is this a bug? Already asked this on Amazon forum, but with no response.

Comment: Mind that RDS has 2 backup options: the backup window, in which you can restore your DB to any point in time within that window, and DB snapshots, so you can restore to the snapshot point in time.

Comment: And "Anybody know what is going on? Is this a bug?" is not a very good question, please be more precise in what is your test, expected and actual results.